# Download Monero Blockchain data and the official client

Tags: blockchain

Is there a site where I can just download the entire monero blockchain instead of waiting for it to sync? And where do I get the official client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both blockchain and clients are on https://getmonero.org/downloads/.

The blockchain (https://downloads.getmonero.org/blockchain.raw) needs to be imported once downloaded. Verification is recommended, but it can be turned off for speed (current master is a lot faster for this, so the coming release will be too).

Current master is also *much* friendlier on the download size needed (barely more than blockchain.raw).

Comment: how big is the raw file size as of today?

Comment: Raw size is something like 30 GB or so.